# Advantages and Disadvantages of appium

Tags: appium

I am new to appium. Anyone already experienced with the appium could tell the pros and cons of appium. It should help to use the appium in correct way.

Answer (score 7):

*Advantages:*

1. Support for both platforms iOS and android.
2. Support for continuous integration
3. Doesn't require access to your source code or library. You are testing with which you will actually ship.
4. Support for various frameworks.

*Disadvantage:*

1. Doesn't support image comparison.

This is what i have figured so far in 2 months. You will actually know when you start using it based on your project requirement.

Comment: Gaurav is 100% correct when stating "You will actually know when you start using it based on your project requirement." I have been using it for 4 months now and have had a blast. I started with Java and moved to Ruby. One of the sub projects is "ruby_console" its like the built in App Inspector but with more power.

Comment: How does image comparison work in other testing frameworks? Are you talking about generating screenshots and then comparing them with prior screenshots to look for image regressions?

(FYI: I'm a member of the Appium team)

Comment: is there any issue between appium and firebase, cuz the tester in our company says that there is a problem and he can't make the tests cuz of the backend. thanks in advance

Comment: How can we test for dynamically generated UI components?

Answer (score 4):

*Advantages:*

- Supports any programming languages (thanks to json wire protocol)
- Able to test iOS and Android
- Supports automation of hybris, native and webapps.
- supports multiple frameworks.
- Commonly used programming API's can be integrated.
- cross-platform
- open source (free)
- Can run app through appium server without manipulating the app.
- No source code required(unlike robotium)
- CI compatible with jenkins, saucelabs(so far from my experience)
- Able to run on selenium grid.
- Doesn't require an APK for use, although automating certain apps do.
- Selenium webdriver compatible.

*Disadvantages:*

- Image comparison
- Long time to configure appium for both android and iOS.
- Too many unexpected errors.

Comment: Too many unexpected errors. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @Md.Zishan Paya for example these https://github.com/appium/sample-code/issues/134

Comment: please can u tell me does it work with firebase or no, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Advantages:

1. Supports most of the programming languages like java, ruby.
2. Use can test both iOS and Android platform.
3. Supports automation of hybrid, native and web apps.
4. cross-platform.
5. Backend is Selenium so you will get all selenium functionality.
6. Doesn't require an APK for use.

Disadvantages:

1. Limited support for Android < 4.1.
2. Under Developing stage can't use for a big project initially.
3. Appium documentation is a little weak.
4. Less availability of tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

*Advantages* for my situation (trying to build fully automated, i.e. build-triggered for desktop browser and mobile browsers using the same data-driven ruby libraries and a locally developed DSL)

1. Uses Selenium.
2. Handles both Android and iOS
3. Handles simulators/emulators and real devices

*Disadvantages*

1. Unexpected errors including disappearing node.exe.
2. Documentation is spotty and site is awkward to navigate.
3. Clearly still in shake out stages but I also think it has a bright future, bolstered by its parent SauceLabs which seems to be doing well.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it to develop an iOS app test framework with C# and more often than not it feels a bit raw and undercooked. I feel that the Java, Ruby and Python languages are better supported than C# and many days it's an uphill battle at the office. With all that in mind I think it does have a bright future so I'll stick with it